# Coloring a vtkUnstructuredGrid by vector magnitude

Tags: python, qt, vtk, paraview

I'm trying to display an EnSight file in a Qt/VTK application. More precisely, I want to display a specific EnSight part and color it by the magnitude of one of the vector variables. As far as I understand, the output of the VTK reader is a `vtkMultiBlockDataSet`, with one block per part. Each block is a `vtkUnstructuredGrid` and the variables are specific arrays in the `pointdata`.

The code I have so far is below. Unfortunately, it shows a uniform color (when the same file loaded in ParaView it shows some local variations).

Obviously I'm missing something, but I can't figure where. I'd be grateful for any hints.

```
casefile = "data/Results/exported/blahblah.case"
part_id = 0
var_id = 2

reader = vtk.vtkGenericEnSightReader()
reader.SetCaseFileName(casefile)
reader.Update()

# Color map
colormap = vtk.vtkLookupTable()
colormap.SetHueRange(0.667, 0.0)
colormap.SetVectorModeToMagnitude()
colormap.Build()

multiblock = reader.GetOutput()
ugrid = multiblock.GetBlock(part_id)
pointdata = ugrid.GetPointData()
data = pointdata.GetArray(var_id)
data_range = data.GetRange(-1)

mesh_mapper = vtk.vtkDataSetMapper()
mesh_mapper.SetInput(ugrid)
mesh_mapper.SetColorModeToDefault()
mesh_mapper.SetScalarRange(data_range)
mesh_mapper.SetScalarVisibility(True)
mesh_mapper.SetLookupTable(colormap)
#
mesh_actor = vtk.vtkActor()
mesh_actor.SetMapper(mesh_mapper)
mesh_actor.GetProperty().SetDiffuseColor(1., 1., 1.)

renderer = vtk.vtkRenderer()
renderer.AddActor(mesh_actor)
renderer.AddActor2D(colorbar)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
colormap = vtk.vtkLookupTable()
colormap.SetHueRange(0.667, 0.0)
colormap.SetVectorModeToMagnitude()
colormap.Build()
```

Will generate a lookuptable with a range between 0 and 1. Is this the data range from your example data?

If not, set the data range to the min/max values in the `data_range` tuple and then call `Build()` - I think this should help - do you have example data?